# Android Emulator says can't play this video

Tags: android, android-videoview

Whenever I write this code this error occurs: can't play this file.

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.my); 
        VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.idVideoView);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);        
        videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Raw folder supports video file. but please note which format it is. Check this.

https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core

Comment: i am playing .mp4 file and code is running on device

Comment: then what's your issue? @user2239842

Comment: Why it is not playing on Emulator?(I mentioned there Android Emulator)